# What is the current directory used by fs module functions?

Tags: node.js, express, fs

What is the current directory when a method in the `fs` module is invoked in a typical node.js/Express app?  For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFile("abc.jpg", "binary");
```

What is the default folder used to locate abc.jpg?  Is it dependent on the containing script's folder location?

Is there a method to query the current directory?

---

My file structure is:

```
ExpressApp1/
           app.js
           routes/
                 members.js
```

In members.js I have a `fs.createWriteStream("abc")` and file `abc` was created in `ExpressApp1/`

Comment: __dirname global variable will give the directory of the file it is logged from.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's the directory where the node interpreter was started from (aka the current working directory), not the directory of script's folder location (thank you robertklep).

Also, current working directory can be obtained by:

```
process.cwd()
```

For more information, you can check out: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

EDIT: Because you started app.js by `node app.js` at `ExpressApp1` directory, every relative path will be relative to "ExpressApp1" folder, that's why `fs.createWriteStream("abc")` will create a write stream to write to a file in `ExpressApp1/abc`. If you want to write to `ExpressApp1/routes/abc`, you can change the code in `members.js` to:

```
fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "abc"));
```

For more:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

Comment: It's not the directory where the script is located, it's the directory where the `node` interpreter was started from (aka the current working directory).

Comment: @ardilgulez I have expanded my question with my experience.